# Having trouble with a beginner JavaScript for-loop problem, sorting through data in an array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need to sort through a series of serial numbers, keeping only the ones that are both 6 digits long, and also odd. I feel my code should do this, but it seems to let some even numbers through into my final array.

Here is my code:

```
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
    console.log(serialNumbers);
    const efficientSerialNumbers = [];
    for (let i=0; i<serialNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (serialNumbers[i].length === 6 && serialNumbers[i] % 2 !== 0) {
            efficientSerialNumbers.push(serialNumbers[i])
        }
    }
    return efficientSerialNumbers;
}
```

I feel like my statement serialNumbers[i] % 2 !== 0 should prevent this?

Comment: what are `serialNumbers` ? What is the format?

Comment: They are numbers. The array might look like: [32438, 34193, 149143, 4329429, 98537, 238791, 23492, 298342] for example.

Comment: Your code can be reduced if you use `filter()` The basic idea: `const sns = [32438, 34193, 149143, 4329429, 98537, 238791, 23492, 298342]; const effSns = sns.filter(sn => sn.toString().length === 6 && sn % 2 !== 0); console.log(effSns);`

Comment: const efficientBulbs = (arr) => arr.filter((item, index) => String(item).length === 6 && index %2 === 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your 6 digit number to string and then check for length
You can  not find `.length` of a number

```js
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
    const efficientSerialNumbers = [];
    for (let i=0; i<serialNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(serialNumbers[i]) && parseInt(serialNumbers[i]).toString().length === 6 && serialNumbers[i] % 2 !== 0) {
            efficientSerialNumbers.push(serialNumbers[i])
        }
    }
    return efficientSerialNumbers;
}

console.log(findEfficientBulbs([123451,123452, 123453, 123454, 123455, 123456, 123457, 123458, 123459, 123450, 009099]))
```

Comment: Ah ok, so numbers do not have a length in the same way strings do then?

Comment: No only string have length property